# WinPython and OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I use WinPython to write my python programs. I need to solve the task of detecting faces in a video stream. I have installed opencv-python to WinPython using this command:

```
pip install opencv-python==3.4.0.12
```

When I run the following code, I get a False:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, img = cap.read()
print(ret)
```

[image: example]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like legit function result. As you can see, from [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read) VideoCapture::read function returns retval and image, in case there was image to return. Apparently, "False" value of the `ret` variable in your code means that there was no image.

Edit:

I looked up documentation and here's what i've found:

"If no frames has been grabbed (camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file), the methods return false and the functions return NULL pointer."

Comment: Hi! This code only should to capture image from camera and it shouldn't detecting faces

Comment: Sorry, I've misread documentation. I've edited comment, so it will be more helpful.

Comment: I suggest, you try to run your code not with the device, but with video file(.avi, for example), to make sure that the code is working properly.

Comment: Thank you! I can read .mp4 file. I think it's my web cam error!